# getting error when I create extension method for UrlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

I'm using this [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055415/adding-id-and-title-to-url-slugs-in-asp-net-mvc?answertab=active#tab-top) for having clean URLs in my application :

```
public static class UrlEncoder
    {
        public static string ToFriendlyUrl(this UrlHelper helper,
            string urlToEncode)
        {
            urlToEncode = (urlToEncode ?? "").Trim().ToLower();

            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char ch in urlToEncode)
            {
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case ' ':
                        url.Append('-');
                        break;
                    case '&':
                        url.Append("and");
                        break;
                    case '\'':
                        break;
                    default:
                        if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') ||
                            (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'))
                        {
                            url.Append(ch);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            url.Append('-');
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return url.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and I'm using above class with this way :

```
<a href="/Products/@item.Id/@Url.ToFriendlyUrl(item.Name)">@item.Name</a>
```

but I'm getting this error and extension not working:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ToFriendlyUrl' and no extension method 'ToFriendlyUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've added these using directive :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

I tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378180/urlhelper-extension-method-not-working) but still I have same error :

```
@UrlHelper.ToFriendlyUrl(item.Name)
```

and used this directive `using System.Web.Http.Routing;` instead `using System.Web.Mvc;`but still I have same error.
it seems that `UrlHelper` belongs to another assembly , I don't know.

**any Ideas?**
**Thanks in your Advise**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to include the namespace of `UrlEncoder` class in your view:

```
@using Mynamespace
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error when calling a UrlHelper extension method from my view, but the solution was slightly different so I'll share it in case it helps someone else:

In my extension class, I needed to replace `using System.Web.Http.Routing;` with `using System.Web.Mvc;`

Both resolve `UrlHelper`, but the MVC reference is what you need to use it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the interface(**IUrlHelper**) instead of class name(UrlHelper) as first parameter.

```
public static class UrlEncoder  
    {  
        public static string ToFriendlyUrl(this **IUrlHelper** helper,
            string urlToEncode)  
         {  
         //your code  
        }  
}
```

Comment: Please read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - in order to format code as code, you only need to mark it with 3 backticks or to indent it. Could you please [edit] your answer and format it correctly.